# convert utc date time to utc timestamp in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, utc

I need to convert date time to UTC timestamp. but the problem is; different systems returns different timestamps based on machine timezone.

example:
date1 = "2022-05-17 04:35:38"

UTC timestamp is:
1652762138

Code:

```
date1 = "2022-05-17 04:35:38"
date_utc = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp())
```

the problem as I mentioned is it returns number based on machine timezone.

I need simplest solution please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution so I'll post it here if anyone else got my problem:

you can use timezone as:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

date1 = "2022-05-17 04:35:38"

utc_timestamp = int(datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())

# will return 1652762138
```

Comment: you could simplify by using [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) instead of `strptime`